# как отвечать на сообщения отправленные ботом в группу?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram, telebot

объясню свою задумку, пользователь пишет боту о гипотетической проблеме, бот пересылает это сообщение в группу, в группе это выглядит так:

id пользователя: сообщение пользователя

моя цель - это возможность отвечать на сообщение пользователя в группе, и что бы бот пересылал или перепечатывал мой ответ в его чат с этим пользователем

надеюсь понятно объяснил)

вот функция отправки сообщения в группу:

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
def messages(message):
    if int(message.chat.id) == int(config.owner):
        try:
            chatId=message.text.split(': ')[0]
            text=message.text.split(': ')[1]
            bot.send_message(chatId, text)
        except:
            pass
    else:
        bot.send_message(config.owner, str(message.chat.id) + ': ' + message.text)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Ваш вопрос был обработан, в течении 30 минут вы вы получите ответ',message.chat.username)
```

Comment: Зачем вы **КРИЧИТЕ**?

Comment: да просто капсом привычнее писать

Comment: Нажмите [править](/posts/1475122/edit) и уберите весь капс, а так же подумайте над формулировкой.

Answer (score 0):

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def forward(message):
    bot.forward_message(chat_id='******', from_chat_id='-******', message_id='*****')
```

`forward_message` принимает аргументы (список всех можно посмотреть в оф. документации) `chat_id` это id бота (посмотреть можно в тг боте `get my id`), `from_chat_id` это id группы (его тоже можно посмотреть через IDbot просто скиньте ссылку на группу), `message_id = chat_id`, то есть id нужно использовать один и тот же

И заключительное, как ответить на такое сообщение:

Бот пересылает сообщение пользователя в группу вместе с id пользователя, вы свайпаете влево (если с телефона) или выбираете ответить (если с компа), пишите в начале сообщения id пользователя которое отправил бот, ставите двоеточие и пишите ответ.

Выглядит это так(Б-бот, В-вы):

> Б:  id:message
>
> В:  (отвечаете) id:ваше сообщение